# ODI 12c - Reverse engineer txt - line break problem

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I have the next flow. I need to reverse engineer a txt file in ODI. The file it's for unix (lf line terminator), but when I try to reverse engineer the file I have the next error:

> com.sunopsis.tools.core.exception.SnpsSimpleMessageException:
>   ODI-15116: There is not enough data in the target file to proceed with
>   the reverse-engineering. Please make sure the file has at least one
>   non-empty line and number of rows to skip is correct.     at
>   com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpTable.fileDataStoreReversePhase1(SnpTable.java:1059)
>     at
>   com.sunopsis.graphical.frame.edit.EditFrameSnpTable.doReverseFromTable(EditFrameSnpTable.java:804)
>     at
>   com.sunopsis.graphical.frame.edit.EditFrameSnpTable.jButtonReverseDelimiter_ActionPerformed(EditFrameSnpTable.java:3035)
>     at
>   com.sunopsis.graphical.frame.edit.EditFrameSnpTable$IvjEventHandler.actionPerformed(EditFrameSnpTable.java:354)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at
>   java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)   at
>   oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
>     at
>   oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

After I open the file in notepad and do the next steps (change file from linux (LF) to windows (CRLF)): notepad ++ > edit > EOL Conversion Windows) it works.

Does someone knows why it works to reverse only windows files, even if ODI is installed on linux?

Comment: Isn't there an option where you can configure the line terminator?

Comment: oh .. yes .. I forgot about this ..